# Connecting to a web server over HTTP, code snippet

Tags: android, http

I'v got the following piece of code:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.flashstall.com/json.txt");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("m40", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}
```

When I run it it logs "Error in http connection java.net.UnkownHostException: www.flashstall.com".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you have a network error. The [UnknownHostException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) is thrown when the hostname cannot be resolved. In your case its: `www.flashstall.com.`

Looks like you cannot access the site www.flashstall.com because perhaps you are not connected to the internet.

How to verify:

Open your adb shell `$>adb shell` and try to ping www.flashstall.com.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can't have json.txt as a part of the URI.

Comment: Why, is it because of the .txt extension?

Comment: json.txt is a file. Your webserver won't "understand" your call.
Check what adrian wrote below =)

Answer (score 0):

For a basic example convert your json.txt file into a php file and just echo your data. Then you'll be able to use it as:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.flashstall.com/json.php");
```

For a more detailed example check [here.](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)